# Move encrypted String from Oracle DB to DB2

Tags: encryption, plsql, oracle11g, db2

I have a normal String `athakur@test.com`. It is stored encrypted in oracle DB with some encryption key. The algo used is not available in DB2 and I want the same data in DB2.

I am not able to directly transfer data by copy paste as the characters are different it basically gives different characters when I paste it from SQL developer to data studio. So I am trying to convert encrypted data to hex and then converting hex to data in DB2. But that does not seem to work.

Encrypted data in hex using `rawtohex` is `1E70A8495CEC19EEBDBA7A652344C850B1266E74247A9306` but in DB2 when I do

```
select x'1E70A8495CEC19EEBDBA7A652344C850B1266E74247A9306' from dual;
```

I am getting null.

Any idea what am I missing or any other way to replicate data?

Answer (score 0):

What version and platform of DB2?

Your statement should work, assuming you're on a version that has Oracle's dual table instead of the sysibm.sysdummy1 equivalent.

It does work for me, though the display value is unreadable of course.  I suspect you really want

```
select hex(x'1E70A8495CEC19EEBDBA7A652344C850B1266E74247A9306') 
from dual;
```

You can't display the encrypted value directly as it isn't valid displayable characters.  The best you can do

```
insert x'1E70A8495CEC19EEBDBA7A652344C850B1266E74247A9306'
into mytbl;

select hex(myfld)
from mytbl;
```

Make sure that you define myfld as `CHAR(24) FOR BIT DATA`

Comment: No `1E70A8495CEC19EEBDBA7A652344C850B1266E74247A9306` is already hex value. I want back the corresponding encrypted value.

Comment: You can't display the encrypted value directly, you'll have to use `HEX()` to display the hex representation of the encrypted value.  See my update.